# Setting FK for a form in a formest

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms

I am trying to set the FK for a submitted form and it's griping at me! Oh dear!

This is the error that I am getting upon submitting the form.

IntegrityError at /build-classroom/
reports_classroom.user_id may not be NULL

I think it has something to do with either `exclude = ("user",)` in ClassroomForm or perhaps it is related to my view code `classroom.user = request.user`

**forms.py**

```
class ClassroomForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Classroom
        exclude = ("user",)
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_method = 'post'
        self.helper.form_action = ''
        self.helper.form_tag = False
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Fieldset('Create a New Classroom','name'),
            )

        super(ClassroomForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class StudentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        exclude = ("classroom",)
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_method = 'post'
        self.helper.form_action = ''
        self.helper.form_tag = False
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Fieldset(
                'Add Student',
                Div('first_name', css_class="large-5 columns"),
                Div('last_name', css_class="large-5 columns"),
                Div('birth_date', css_class="large-2 columns"),
                Div('gender', css_class="large-2 columns"),
                Div('ethnicity', css_class="large-2 columns"),
                Div('race', css_class="large-2 columns"),
                Div('free_or_reduced_lunch','prior_special_ed_services', css_class="large-6 columns"),
            ),
            )
        super(StudentForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required
def build_classroom(request):
    # Empty formset forms should be required
    class RequiredFormSet(BaseFormSet):
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(RequiredFormSet, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            for form in self.forms:
                form.empty_permitted = False
    StudentFormSet = formset_factory(StudentForm, max_num=100, formset=RequiredFormSet)
    if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
        classroom_form = ClassroomForm(request.POST) # A form bound to the POST data
        # Create a formset from the submitted data
        student_formset = StudentFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if classroom_form.is_valid() and student_formset.is_valid():
            classroom = classroom_form.save(commit=False)
            classroom.user = request.user
            for form in student_formset.forms:
                student = form.save(commit=False)
                student.classroom = classroom
                student.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/') # Redirect to a 'success' page
    else:
        classroom_form = ClassroomForm()
        student_formset = StudentFormSet()

    # For CSRF protection
    # See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/ 
    c = {'classroom_form': classroom_form,
         'student_formset': student_formset,
        }
    c.update(csrf(request))

    return render_to_response('reports/build_classroom.html', c)
```

**build_classroom.html**

```
<form action="" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
    <div class="section">
        {% crispy classroom_form %}
    </div>
    {{ student_formset.management_form|crispy }}
    {% for form in student_formset.forms %}
    <div class="item">
      {% crispy form %}
      <p style=""><a class="delete button secondary" href="#">Delete</a></p>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <a id="add" class='button' href="#">Add another student</a>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class='button' />
</form>
```

**models.py**

```
class Classroom(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __unicode__ (self):
        return self.name
```

I left out a bit of jQuery and other code.

Comment: It looks like `user` is a required in your models.py. Try to check it.

Comment: Isn't form.is_valid() checking for that?

Comment: I'm not sure about it, cause you excluded this field from form.

Comment: I think my problem is here: `classroom = classroom_form.save(commit=False)
            classroom.user = request.user
            for form in student_formset.forms:
                student = form.save(commit=False)
                student.classroom = classroom
                student.save()`